# Submit form in new window and redirect current page not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to submit a form in a new window and redirect the current window to another page.

The following code works in Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function refreshpage()
{
    window.location='form_search.php';
}
</script>

<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="print_compare.php" target="_blank">
    <input type="submit" name="btn_compare" id="btn_compare" value="" onclick="javascript:refreshpage();" />
<form>
```

Comment: `location.href = 'form_search.php';`

Comment: Also, because you're not preventing the default action (form submission), your redirect may not get a chance to fire.

Comment: location.href = 'form_search.php';  
i try this  but it's not work for chrome again.

Comment: Note that [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) is technically a read-only property, and assigning a value to it is browser-specific behavior that should not be relied upon. The use of `location.href`, as Jack commented, is a browser-agnostic way to do it.

Comment: i want to send some value to print_compare.php page too.

Comment: @user3466898 then why don't you post to `print_compare.php`, do something with the data, then `header("Location: form_search.php");` from there?

Comment: @scrowler It submits the form in a new window and the current window needs to redirect.

Comment: To add to my comment below...if you feel that your question has been answered, rather than posting "thank you" as either an answer or a comment, please mark the answer that you feel best resolved the problem as accepted by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. You can also upvote the accepted answer and any other answers you found helpful once you have at least 15 rep.

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
window.location.replace("form_search.php");
```

or

```
window.location.href = "form_search.php";
```

Comment: From the comments: "location.href = 'form_search.php'; i try this but it's not work for chrome again."

Comment: Checked with chrome, window.location.href works fine.

Comment: 'window.location' is the same thing as 'location' (in browsers).

Comment: ^^ Thats true. But I'm clueless with  'it's not work'. Another jQ style approach is: $(location).attr('href','form_search.php');

Comment: @effone Don't worry, everyone is clueless with "it's not work".

Comment: In jQ lingo that would be `$(location).prop('href', 'form_search.php');` :)

Comment: ok thank you for everyone that's work  if action=default (form submittion)